# colorBars not working in BarChat react.js

Tags: reactjs, frontend, bar-chart

Bars are not showing in colors. Here is my code.

```
 <BarChart
      colorBars
       data={this.state.data}
       width={350}
       height={400}
       margin={{top: 10, bottom: 50, left: 50, right: 10}}
       />
```

Here is my output :- 
[click Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1nWWO.png)

Comment: What library are you getting your `BarChart` component from?

Comment: Are you passing colors in **this.state.data**??

Comment: import {BarChart} from 'react-d3-components'

Comment: following this link to implement color bars :- https://rma-consulting.github.io/react-easy-chart/bar-chart/index.html#introduction